# Magento 2.2.2 customers receiving multiple shipment emails

Tags: magento2.2

I have problem on one the client magento site. For some reason customers were getting multiple shipment emails. They are getting it around 10 per order, and not all of them, only few random customers as I can see for now, so I can't figure it out why is that happening.
I can't find solution for it, and I looked everywhere. If you have any suggestion or possible solution please write.
Thank you!

Comment: `Magento\Sales\Model\Order\Email\Sender\ShipmentSender`  check if you have overridden this class and debug it

Comment: No, it's not override I checked that also. :/